# facebook login not working while creating an android app by converting a web app using phone gap

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am working on a project for which i need to login from facebook. I have to create an android app for same project as well and required same facebook login in it. so i have implemented my web application  for which facebook login is working fine. then i converted it in android app using same source code when i tried to login from android app it is open in browser and not working throwing error.

"given url is not allowed bty the application configuration:one or more of the given url is not allowed by the app settings."

I need a solution from which i can convert my same web application into android, iphone etc.

code:

### app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      status: true, 
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

### home.js

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl',["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Login please';
    $scope.FBLogin = function(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
               console.log(response);
             });
            } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
        console.log("dsgfds");  
    };
}]);
```

//........updated code implemented using ngcordova.................//

### Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="facebookApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/customjs/fbapp.js"></script>  

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="home">
                    <div id="fb-root" >

                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <a ng-click="facebookLogin()" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Login via Facebook</button></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### fbapp.js

```
        var app = angular.module("facebookApp",['ngCordova']);

        app.controller('mainCtrl',["$scope","$cordovaOauth", function($scope, $cordovaOauth /*$cordovaFacebook*/) {
    $scope.facebookLogin = function() {

$cordovaOauth.facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ["public_profile","email"])
        .then(function(success) {

            alert("welcome1");

          }, function (error) {
          // error
          alert("error :"+ error);
        });
    }
    }]);
```

### error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=facebook-app&p1=Err…92.168.1.3%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4526
n @ angular.js:321
g @ angular.js:4487
fb @ angular.js:4409
Ac.c @ angular.js:1691
Ac @ angular.js:1712
fe @ angular.js:1606
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:30423
i @ jquery.min.js:2
j.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: check this out https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491
...one more thing if you are using angular why you use window.fbAsyncInit ... make a separate service for that ... to know more go to developer.facebook using angular.

Comment: i already done this and its working fine for me when i am login from web application but when i implemented the android app from the same source code it is not working and throws an error.

Comment: since you are using android phonegap ... so basically you have to use facebook cordova plugin... you cant achieve it through web as bcoz in phonegap all the files are in local but local file url will not work in developer  facebook's app settings.

Comment: @Banik i tried to convert my code by using facebook cordova plugin but it won't work for me it through some error i.e. mentioned in edit section.

Comment: ng-cordova is missing into your html and as well as there is no need to add fbapp.js since you are using ng-cordova it will call its facebook service.

Comment: @Banik it gives me same error while i added ng-cordova.js. and fbapp implemented by me to handle login

Comment: @Banik i added ng-cordova in my index.html and using cordovaOauth for login but it is again throwing error. it is not working on browser and android app as well. on android it neither throws sucess nor error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved using deviceready event.

deviceready event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code loads, a custom loading image displays. However, JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads. This means the web app may potentially call a Cordova JavaScript function before the corresponding native code becomes available.

The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs.

```
var app = angular.module("facebookApp",['ngCordova','ngCordovaOauth','ngRoute','ngStorage']);

    app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location, $http) {

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use device APIs
                app.config(["$cordovaFacebookProvider",function($cordovaFacebookProvider) {
                  var appID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
                  var version = "v2.5"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
                  $cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
                }]);
            }


            $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
                 // $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile"])
                     $cordovaOauth.facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ["public_profile","email"])
                        .then(function(success) {

                             $localStorage.accessToken = success.access_token;

                          }, function (error) {
                          // error
                          alert("error :"+ error);
                        });
           }
```